# Generate specific string from specific seed

Tags: c#, compression, seed

I would like to generate a specific string from a specific seed,
example:

```
string data = "LargeBigData"
string seed = "seed1"

string generatedStringSeed = ToSeed (data, seed) 
// Output: 20b-a46
```

and vice versa:

```
string OriginalData = SeedToString (generatedStringSeed) 
// Output: "LargeBigData"
```

If a specific number can be generated from a specific seed, any long text can be generated from a simple one, since they are basically numbers.

Is there some algorithm or library to do it?, or it just isn't possible!

I have created an algorithm that compresses any file to a 6,000-8,000 letter key. I would like to create a seed that generates that key. And thus to be able to obtain any file from this simple seed, without security.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here? is this for security purposes?

Comment: I have created an algorithm that compresses any file to a 6,000-8,000 letter key. I would like to create a seed that generates that key. And thus to be able to obtain any file from this simple seed, without security.

Comment: Any link shortener have it's own pair of short-link to full-link, like `Dictionary<string, string>` or database. There's no algorithms (except for more level of archiving)  that can give you what you want